# Binding child DataContext from within DataTrigger

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I have been trying to develop a bar of RadioButtons (styled as ToggleButtons) which select which content is displayed in a ContentControl. I have been able to use a DataTrigger to display the proper view in the ContentControl based on which RadioButton is checked, but I am also trying to bind a view model from the parent DataContext into the child's DataContext, without success. A minimum sample is as follows:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Top" >
            <RadioButton Name="rbShowChild" Content="Show Child" Style="{StaticResource {x:Type ToggleButton}}" />
        </StackPanel>

        <ContentControl Grid.Row="1">
            <ContentControl.Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=rbShowChild}" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Content">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <local:ChildView DataContext="{Binding ChildViewModel, PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High}"/>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </ContentControl.Style>
        </ContentControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The Binding to the ChildViewModel seems to be the part that is not working as expected. For completeness, here is the related ChildView.

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication1.ChildView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="Child" />
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

And the ViewModels:

```
namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public class ChildViewModel
    {
        public string Text { get; set; }

        public ChildViewModel()
        {
            Text = "It works!";
        }
    }

    public class MainWindowViewModel
    {
        public ChildViewModel ChildViewModel { get; set; }

        public MainWindowViewModel()
        {
            ChildViewModel = new ChildViewModel();
        }
    }
}
```

And the MainWindow DataContext is set as follows:

```
        var window = new MainWindow()
        {
            DataContext = new MainWindowViewModel()
        };
        window.Show();
```

The Output window (with PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High) shows this:

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 3 : Cannot find element that provides DataContext. BindingExpression:Path=ChildViewModel; DataItem=null; target element is 'ChildView' (Name=''); target property is 'DataContext' (type 'Object')
```

which leads me to think that somehow the MainWindow.DataContext is not the DataContext used to resolve the "{Binding ChildViewModel}" expression in the trigger, but I couldn't find any DataContext property on the trigger, nor have I been able to find anything in my searches to suggest an answer for this.

I would very much appreciate any suggestions to resolve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE: Looks like the issue is with how you are setting the data context.

Set the DataContext of the window in the XAML, then set the data context of the `ContentControl` to the `ChildViewModel`. Then set the actual displayed `Content` (AKA ChildView) `Value`. The `ContentControl` is the host of this view, so it should be the `DataContext` supplier. I myself am a little unsure the exact mechanics going on, but I know for fact the below code works.

*NOTE* Your XML namespaces may vary from the code below. Adjust accordingly.

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <!-- Data Context added here OR in code-behind initialize-->
    <local:MainWindowViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Top" >
        <RadioButton Name="rbShowChild" Content="Show Child" Style="{StaticResource {x:Type ToggleButton}}" />
    </StackPanel>

    <!-- Bind the ContentControls Data context-->
    <ContentControl DataContext="{Binding ChildViewModel}" Grid.Row="1">
        <ContentControl.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=rbShowChild}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Content">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <!-- Just simply set the view content here, no binding.-->
                                <local:ChildView />
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </ContentControl.Style>
    </ContentControl>
</Grid>
```

Doing this, I have run your application just fine in a project.

Comment: Thanks for your response, Toskr. I tried both of those, but I don't think it is solving my problem. The MainWindow DataContext seems to work fine, even in the original project. It is the ChildView DataContext that is not getting set. When you say it is working for you after these changes, are you seeing the bound text string "It works!" when you click the button, which is supposed to be getting displayed from the Child view, or only the string "Child" (which is not bound, but just in the XAML)? The trigger is working to display the child view, just the child DataContext is not getting set.

Comment: I am seeing the string "It works" displayed. Perhaps post for info on how and where you set your data contexts.

Comment: The original code to create the MainWindow and set its DataContext is in App.OnStartup(). I also added your suggested change into both the MainWindow constructor and the XAML. I'm not sure why it is working for you but not for me.

Comment: Also, if I add
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ChildViewModel.Text}"/>
into my MainWindow, it displays "It works!" there just fine, which again means my MainWindow DataContext is set properly.
Does it work for you when setting the MainWindow DataContext from App.OnStartup, and without setting it again in either of the places you proposed?

Comment: I wont be at my computer till the morning, so ill dig in deeper then. However this feels like it may be one of thos situations where you may be overlooking some small error that is causing things to not work as expected. I would suggest going through things and looking carefully. For example, have you done anything in the child view code behind? Anything that could be breaking the binding for the child at run time? Perhaps something you forgot to remove?

Comment: Also. Im taking a shot in the dark, because im not sure if it makes a difference.. but where you set the name of the radio button, trying using "x:Name" instead. Maybe a xaml referencing issue? Sincerely Doubt it, but its worth a try.

Comment: There is nothing in the codebehind other than the default (constructor which calls InitializeComponent). I made an empty project and posted all the code above, so there shouldn't be anything else. Thank you for your assistance. It is somewhat helpful knowing that there is not a problem in the syntax of my binding, and I should look elsewhere. Thanks.

Comment: Changing Name to x:Name for the RadioButton had no effect.

Comment: Figured. When i get home tomorrow ill put the project i did on GitHub for you to look and compare.

Comment: Okay brother. After this mind boggling adventure, I hope in about 5 seconds when you copy paste the updated code you will jump with joy. It appears I was initially misleading when I claimed the other code worked, not realizing I actually did make some changes -- So feel free to come over to my house and slap me in the head. Anyways, I updated the original post with the updated XAML and a little more explanation. I hope this helps you, and it absolutely 100% works for me with that exact code -- this time I'd put my life on it.

Comment: Thanks Toskr. That worked! In the real app, I have multiple child views, each of which wants its own VM, so I'll have to figure out how to scale that solution, but I am very grateful to have something that works.

Comment: In case anyone stumbles upon this in the future, I removed setting the ContentControl's DataContext, and instead added another Setter in the DataTrigger:                             <Setter Property="DataContext" Value="{Binding ChildViewModel}">